# How to edit id3-tags (MP3 tags) in Marshmallow?

Tags: sd-card, 6.0-marshmallow, permissions, mp3, id3-tag

Ok, so I'm not got to act like I know what I'm talking about, but I've done a fair bit of googling and stuff like 'write permissions' have come up over and over again when searching id3 tag editors.

My question is, how do I edit my music titles? ie album name and song title. Some of my songs have unknown artist or album.

I have a LG G4 with marshmallow 6.0, my old G4 had lollipop and I could edit my music with an app. That phone got run over, my new G4 now has marshmallow. I bought it a few weeks ago.

The apps that claimed to work don't, black music player had a built in editor and it looked promising, it let me edit my music but after exiting the app and going back in, it had changed back to the original title.(two hours of my life I can't get back.)

So is there anyway around this with a simple fix? Nothing too technical please like 'rooting' whatever that is....or I've read you can convert your external sd card to become an extension of your internal storage somehow...and I've heard bad things about that too, like lag and storage issues.

I just want to organise my music....something I enjoy doing.

So any ideas would be great 
Thanks,
Beck.

Comment: This app should work: **[Star Music Tag Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.music.star.startag&hl=en)**

Comment: Unfortunately the app didn't work...I had the same problem as black music player....I selected the sd card before saving...I think it's a developer issue with marshmallow, I had no problems editing with lollipop in file manager, I just don't have that option now with marshmallow. 

Comment: I'm not sure how those apps operate – but obviously they edit the `.mp3` files directly. They might or might not trigger the [media scanner](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/media-scanner/info) afterwards, so it might only *appear* they did nothing. Have you checked the edited files e.g. on your PC? Or tried to trigger the media-scanner manually after an edit (e.g. by rebooting the device)?

Comment: I've been reading numerous post on endless forums and it seems to be a floor with marshmallow 6.0....I had an LG G4 with lollipop and I had no issues editing my music titles (I could do this from file manager) and id3ditor app. Now my new G4 has marshmallow 6.0 and I can't edit anything....I only have the option to move or share now not edit. I just use the music player that came with the phone, the titles haven't changed looking at them on my computer...I can't efit them on my laptop either. Boo0o0o0!

Answer (score 1):

You need not rely on the apps that help you edit the MP3 tags easily.. As @Somberi said, maybe the developers could have abandoned their projects..

There's a very tedious solution anyway, by which you can edit the ID3 tags manually.

**Steps:**

1. Download any **[Hex Editor](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=hex%20editor)** app for Android.
2. Open the mp3 file using that Hex Editor.
3. Scroll to the end of the file..
   The last 128bytes over there is used to store the metadata (ID3 tags)
4. Just note the last 128bytes & try to recognize the tag-names used there by [converting each byte to corresponding ASCII](http://www.asciitohex.com/). For example, the hex bytes `45 6D 69 6E 65 6D` corresponds to the ASCII string `Eminem` ;)

Just change it as required (by converting your ASCII text to Hex bytes) & overwrite it in the corresponding location. Also note that each tag-name is separated by a sequence of spaces (`20 20 20 20 ......` in Hex), or in some cases, sequence of null-bytes (`00 00 00 00 ......`), which varies for different ID3 versions.

(This might also help: [A Quick Study on MP3 file structure](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/a-quick-study-on-mp3-file-structure/) )

When you need to edit multiple MP3 files, this process is really exhausting..
In that case, you may wait till the app developers update their apps (with proper permissions) for Marshmallow, or you can do it easily on your computer, even using VLC Media Player (Tools->Media Information)

Comment: Oh for reals.... I have VLC, that would be so much easier on my laptop, do I need one of those card readers? Or would VLC still be able to edit my tags if I plug my phone into my laptop with the usb?

Comment: Lol all that hex stuff is way beyond my capabilities, knowing my luck I'd end up erasing something important, thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: See: **[How to View and Edit ID3 Audio Tags Using VLC in Computer](https://www.vlchelp.com/view-edit-id3-audio-tags/)**. Copy all your mp3's to PC & do it.. Or do it directly using card reader

Comment: Oh Gokul your a legend, thank you so much, I still have a few unknown albums that couldn't be edited on my old phone. 

Comment: If extra software recommendation is allowed, I would really, really like to say [Poweramp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer) is good for this. Sometimes [Musixmatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.musixmatch.android.lyrify) is also good.

Comment: @iBug Put that as an answer bro if they work.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Because Google put new restrictions on app accessing the file storage in Version 6, many old apps will not work. The solution is to use Version 5 or older devices if you want to stick with the same apps. Or, wait for the apps to get updated. Or, you can search for new apps that are compatible with Version 6.

ID3 tag editing is extremely file IO intensive - it will also waste battery. This is best done on a desktop.

Comment: Oh ffs....lol it's all good. I just swapped my sd card over to my old samsung trend and edited it there. Its a bit time consuming.(that's what I get for being OCD with my music) I guess I'll just have to be patient and wait for the apps to catch up. Thanks